# C# SharpPCap Read Packet Content

Tags: c#, packet-capture, sharppcap

i'm tryin' to read the content of the packets that i've captured with SharpPCap. 
This is my little code

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Retrieve the device list
            var devices = LibPcapLiveDeviceList.Instance;

            // Extract a device from the list
            var device = devices[1];

            // Register our handler function to the
            // 'packet arrival' event
            device.OnPacketArrival +=
                new SharpPcap.PacketArrivalEventHandler(device_OnPacketArrival);

            // Open the device for capturing
            int readTimeoutMilliseconds = 1000;
            if (device is AirPcapDevice)
            {
                // NOTE: AirPcap devices cannot disable local capture
                var airPcap = device as AirPcapDevice;
                airPcap.Open(SharpPcap.WinPcap.OpenFlags.DataTransferUdp, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
            }
            else if (device is WinPcapDevice)
            {
                var winPcap = device as WinPcapDevice;
                winPcap.Open(SharpPcap.WinPcap.OpenFlags.DataTransferUdp | SharpPcap.WinPcap.OpenFlags.NoCaptureLocal, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
            }
            else if (device is LibPcapLiveDevice)
            {
                var livePcapDevice = device as LibPcapLiveDevice;
                livePcapDevice.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException("unknown device type of " + device.GetType().ToString());
            }

            device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);

            device.StartCapture();

            MessageBox.Show("-- Listening on {0}, hit 'Enter' to stop...",
                device.Description);

            // Stop the capturing process
            device.StopCapture();

            // Close the pcap device
            device.Close();

        }

private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Packet.LinkLayerType == PacketDotNet.LinkLayers.Ethernet)
            {
                var packet = PacketDotNet.Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
                var ethernetPacket = (PacketDotNet.EthernetPacket)packet;

                MessageBox.Show(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Packet.Data));
                packetIndex++;
            }
        }
```

I capture a byte[] packet but i don't know how can i read the whole server response.
thank you for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole server response"? SharpPcap (and libpcap/winpcap/airpcap) operate on packets. Assembly of messages is handled at a higher level. There are some 3rd party commercial libraries that use SharpPcap to reassemble tcp and http communications.

Comment: Thank you Chris, for "the whole server response" I mean that I do not know how to put together packages to read the contents of the server response, so you understand better, I would like to read the html code of the response to retrieve some information. thank you again

Comment: What kinds of packets are you trying to capture and reassemble? Your code is capturing all packets. There are dozens or more different protocols used over ethernet... Do you want http only? As I mentioned, there are some commercial products that can do tcp/http reassembly and work with SharpPcap. Its a non-trivial amount of work.